# SharePoint Online domain - using my own

Tags: sharepoint-online, email, custom, domain

I have a person/custom domain that I'd like to use instead of the dumbnameichose.OnMicrosoft.com domain that it gave me. The video they provided to do this seems to suggest that I might be moving some control to Microsoft when I do this. Also, because they suggest setting up a number of DNS records, that SharePoint might also be taking over my email services, which I like just where it is now.

The question(s):

- When setting up my personal/custom domain in SharePoint, does it impact anything with my original domain?
- Does it mean that when someone enters my domain name, that they go to the SharePoint site instead?

I don't want to move my domain to SharePoint but I would prefer to log in with my personal domain name as part of the login. I'd also like to send email from the SharePoint services and they actually get sent, since I do not have email services right now from my SharePoint subscription.